# iPhone MultiThreading: List/Queue

Tags: iphone, multithreading, sdk, queue

I finally got my telnet iPhone application running to send text commands to a device i'm working on but the device isn't as fast as i would like it to be.

As of now when i press a button the phone sends a text command to the device's IP. I want to change it so that a constant process is running and checking a queue every .25 seconds. If the queue has any elements it will send, wait .25 seconds, and check again.

My initial guess is that I should check some iPhone threading libraries so that the buttons that add to queue and the send/checker method could be in separate threads.

I was looking at [iOS Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) specifically at the Operation Queue and Dispatch Queue. Are these queues what I should be looking at or am i completely off here?

**UPDATE**:

I think i found what I want in NSThread however im reading NSMutableArray isnt thread safe. Is there a list type queue or vector that is thread safe in objective c?

**UPDATE 2**:

Could I use a mutablearray and put a lock{} around it everytime i add or remove objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Running a task at a regular time interval sounds like a job for [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). To get this behavior, try creating a timer like so:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(doTask) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Set this object to an instance variable and it will run `-doTask` every 0.25 seconds. As for your background operations, [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592) are probably your best bets. Create a custom NSOperation subclass and override the appropriate methods to run a task in the background.

Answer (score 0):

GCD would be a better solution, NSTimers are not really that good for periodic tasks. Check the `dispatch_after` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not fire the command immediately via an asynchronous method?

Letting the framework handle the multithreading is almost always the right idea, in my experience.

Comment: could you give me an example, Im fairly new at this.